# How to hover over/highlight .img-polaroid border in Bootstrap similar to using .thumbnail class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am trying to figure out how to create a similar effect as the thumbnail effect in Bootstrap, using the img-polaroid class extension.

I know that in the Bootstrap.css file, there is the following code for the thumbnail extension:

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
     box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a.thumbnail:hover,
a.thumbnail:focus {
    border-color: #0088cc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
}
```

And this code I assume is what makes someone able to hover over and highlight the border of any .thumbnail class element.

I am looking at the img-polaroid class code here:

```
.img-polaroid {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

and it seems like I should be able to do the same thing as the .thumbnail code by adding the hover and focus onto another element, like this example I made here:

```
.img-polaroid {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

a.img-polaroid:hover,
a.img-polaroid:focus {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #0088cc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 105, 214, 0.25);
}
```

but it doesn't highlight the border of the image with the img-polaroid class when hovering over the image, like you can do with the .thumbnail class in Bootstrap...

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I know it would be easier to do it just using the .thumbnail class, but I am trying to experiment and see if my way of thinking would work too.

I am using Bootstrap v2.3.1